# text-indent with calc() not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I tested this in IE11, just to be sure. For some reason you can't provide the `text-indent` in a `calc()` statement, even though all other major browsers work correctly. Is there any particular reason for this behaviour?

```
<div class="test">Test 1</div>
<div class="test2">Test 2</div>

.test {
    text-indent: -20px;
}
.test2 {
    text-indent: calc(-20px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8zh4wdvj/

IE11:

[image: IE11]

Chrome:

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a bug with using calc inside a `transform` with IE11. I know that you are not using `transform` here, but in some way `text-indent` can be considered a transformation, so maybe that is the problem.  Here is the link to the bug. https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/814380/

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link!

Comment: `margin-left` seem to work though, strange.